# Synchronize defects and requirements between TFS and HP QC

Tags: hp-quality-center

We use TFS 2010 for (development and requirements) and HP Quality Center for Testing and defects. We currently use [Juvander TFS Bug Synchronizer](http://www.juvander.fi/site/Products/TFSBugItemSynchronizer.aspx) for synchronizing defects and requirements between TFS 2010 and HP Quality Center 10.00.

The problem with Juvander is that it gets slow as the number of projects increase. 
I am asked to investigate alternative tools to sync between TFS and HP QC.

I have looked into the [HP QC Synchronizer](http://update.external.hp.com/qualitycenter/qc100/sync/qcsynchronizer/index.html). But it cannot sync requirements between TFS and HP Quality Center.

I want to know if anyone uses any such synchronizers. Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Regards

Comment: I came across your post while researching a TFS implementaion I am performing for a client. Do you have the latest version of HP tools? The latest version of the HP ALM Synchronizer (documentation at http://update.external.hp.com/qualitycenter/qc110/sync/almsynchronizer/HP-ALM-Sync-UserGuide.pdf) does allow for requirements synchronization. Cheers,